# Trying to $_POST multiple selected options, but not getting any selected options

Tags: php, forms

This is a form and one of the options allows for more than one selection (name="mission[]"). Although I have read some remarks about using brackets in the name, I still keep getting a blank in that section of the form. Any thoughts?
(context: Using PHPMailer and Gmail as SMTP)

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
$firstname = trim($_POST["firstname"]);
//more of these

$mission = trim($_POST["mission"]);
$date = trim($_POST["date"]);
$time = trim($_POST["time"]);

//some other code here

//message in email to be sent

$email_body = "";
$email_body = $email_body . "What I am trying to improve at our clinic: " . $mission . "<br>" ;
```

Here's the html code in a form:

```
<label for="mission" class="col-sm-3 control-label">What are you trying to improve at your clinic?</label>
<div class="col-sm-9">
   <select name="mission[]"  multiple="multiple" class="form-control" style="max-height:75px">
      <option disabled>(Use the Shift key to select more than one)</option>
      <option  value="Decrease noshows"> Decrease patient no-shows</option>
      <option  value="increase # of patients completing a full episode of care"> Increase number of patients completing care.</option>
      <option  value="Improve clinic reviews"> Improve my clinic's reviews.</option>
      <option  value="Increaes physician referrals"> Increase physician referrals.</option>
      <option  value="increase patient referrals"> Increase patient referrals.</option>
      <option  value="improve overall patient satisfaction"> Improve overall patient satisfaction.</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Solution: I went with the following code in the end:

```
$mission_vals = "";
foreach ($mission as $missionselected){
  $mission_vals .= $missionselected . ", "; 
}
```

Comment: You can't call `trim()` on an array. Try removing that and see what happens.

Comment: And check with Firebug which data will be send.

Comment: Debug with `print_r($_POST);`.

Comment: What does the posted HTML have to do with "date" or "time"? Make sure the test-case *accurately* shows the problem, and only the problem, at hand.

Comment: Also, where is the end of the `if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){`?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. And sorry about that, I missed the "date" and "time".

Answer (score 0):

Because you named your select `mission[]` when you call `$_POST["mission"]` PHP is returning an array, not a string.

You need something like:

```
$missionArray = $_POST["mission"];

for ($i=0; $i < count($missionArray); $i++)
{
    $missionArray[$i] = trim($missionArray[$i]);
}
```

Edit:-- The trimming part, more efficiently:

```
$missionArray = array_map('trim', $missionArray);
```